# Error configuring services in an external startup class -Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have recently redployed an application with a minor change (adding a field to model) on azure using azure devops. At the top of the azure function overview page I am getting an error saying "Error configuring services in an external startup class". On clicking the message, the error says "Error configuring services in an external startup class. ---> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
I have checked all the places and couldn't find any reason for null reference in my startup file. Also, the application is working perfectly fine from functionality perspective. The same function was deployed on UAT without any such issue. Is there any way to troubleshoot further or is this message misguiding?
i have checked function app diagnose and solve problem as well but with the same result. I am using consumption tier of azure function.

Comment: not sure who has marked, this as off topic but I got the answer for issue asked above. azure function app has a default behaviour where if a transient error message remains on the overview page for some time even if it is fixed in retry

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I've documented how a minor change in code results in Functions causing this same error (now I know where to find error output).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76807472/how-do-i-find-azure-function-logs-that-show-post-deploy-pre-execution-faults

Comment: Not sure why this was closed - this won't be a DevOps problem.

While the author could perhaps provide some further information (like the code in their startup class) this question is definitely on-topic for StackOverflow, it's about a specific programing problem with tools used by programmers. The answer could be code realted.

 I've voted to re-open it.

Comment: @rdhaundiyal I've voted to re-open this issue as well.  Can you supply some more information like what language the azure function is written in, etc?